# highlight characters in a android listView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView that contains phone contact list. I have implemented search to search from that contact list. But i want highlight the characters from the list based on search criteria entered by user. Please help.

Comment: can't you change color of selected text? it may possible to implement

Answer (score -1):

You can use the help of [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

Add this sort of code (for example) to your `getView` of the adapter:

```
// Set the span to set bold effect
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(longText);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
spannable.setSpan(boldSpan, longTermIndexStart, longTermIndexStart + lastSearchTerm.length(),Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
holder.longView.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: thanks for your response.But where to enter the search result. As i want to highlight that text only.Like if i have "Thanks to android. Welcome to android". Search result is "an" then i want to highlight the "an" portion of "android"